# view a range of search result

Tags: asp-classic, full-text-search

Suppose we've looked for *"**sometext**"* in a text like *"bla bla bla bla bla bla **sometext** bla bla bla bla bla **sometext** bla bla bla bla bla"*.

I expect "bla bla bla bla bla bla **sometext** bla bla bla bla bla ..."
OR
"... bla bla bla bla bla bla **sometext** bla bla bla bla bla ..."

what do you suggest to only display a range of results. Like how Google or vBulletin forum search behave.

I use ASP Classic or Javascript as programming language but a pseudocode will be fine either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will find the first occurence of your search text, and then show the next 135 characters:

```
select
  left(right (myColumn, 1+(len(myColumn) - charindex('sometext', myColumn))),135)
from
some_table where myColumn like '%sometext%'
```

You could edit the 1+ to include more characters that occur before your search text.

Comment: Thanks mate ;) that's what i really needed.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the search result is based on how you query your data.

Use LIKE clause in your SQL statement will do the job.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE title LIKE '%sometext%'
```

Comment: right, I know this ofc. by this query I get whole field value which is that "bla bla ... sometext..." string. I don't want to show all result, but only maximum (e.g.) 135 characters of it.